# Gravitational waves and quantum computing

Tags: gravitational-waves, quantum-computer

Some month ago, I was attending a lecture from a person who worked for LIGO, and eho is now a professor at MIT, about gravitational waves. At the end of the conference, though, time for questions ran out, but I sometime I have this curiosity: do gravitational waves have potential for computing? If so, how much potential do they have, compared to quantum computers ( althiugh I know quantum computers are still a "work in progress")?  Are they studied somewhere, in order to achieve this goal?

Comment: Gravitational waves are far too weak to be used in computing of any sort.

Comment: I would like to say gravitational wave is a classical concept from GR. So let alone that it's very difficult to control it, it will not be a way to achieve quantum computation.

Answer (score 2):

There are people studying whether it is possible to build "quantum gravity quantum computers", that is, quantum computers harnessing things like quantum fluctuations in the causal structure of spacetime, to solve tasks more efficiently than what is possible with "regular" quantum computers. A quick google search will lead you to [some](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=quantum+gravity+quantum+computer&gws_rd=cr&ei=PwwBWLmYBMHKgAa7iLqIAw) of these studies.

If you instead mean whether it is possible to use gravitational waves to do "standard" quantum computing, I'd say the answer is no.
To do something like this you would first of all need to quantize the gravitational waves, that is, have a consistent theory of quantum gravity.

Also, consider how harder it is to experimentally "see" the quantized nature of light (i.e. single photons) with respect to just detecting an electromagnetic wave.
It took huge effort to detect "classical" gravitational waves.
To detect their quantum nature (like gravitons, if that is even a thing in the real world) would be incredibly harder.

To summarize: it can be interesting, and is currently done, to study whether quantum gravity can allow (in theory) to perform things unachievable for regular quantum computers.
But to harness gravitational waves for quantum computing is even further away from the realm of actually doable things.

Comment: No, I didn't mean using them for quantum computing, I just expressed myself badly, sorry for that. My question was : are there any studies now, or possibilities at all, about a computer working with gravitational waves ( didn t mean the quantum nature of that, of course it would be very difficult to achieve that)? If so, would ot wa

Comment: Sorry, I espressed myself badly then. My question was about there are studies about a computer working with just gravitational waves, given the fact that they don t have the problem of keeping the noise low, or having the problem of decoherence, like quantum computers do(of course it would be almost impossible to exploit the quantum nature of gravitational waves, but I didn t mean that). I mentioned quantum computers, because they're the new technology that has been used, and I just wanted to name  it for a comparison between it and an eventual computer based on gravitational waves.